# getting an error when trying to make a regression table

Tags: formatting

When I try to make a regression table I get a 'illegal character in array arg.' on the line with \begin tabular

Moreover, towards the end where I start to place a 'note', I get a message 'undefined control sequence' although I am able to compile an output

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
%\linenumbers

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}

\begin{table}[ht] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\footnotesize
\caption{Determinants}

\begin{tabular}{ l d{2.7} d{2.6} d{4.5} d{4.5}} 
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Fixed Effects Model}


\hline\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\footnotesize
\item Note: \smallscript{ *** \textit{p} $<$.01 ** \textit{p} $<$.05 *\textit{p} $<$.10 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Since you not provide Minimal (non)Working Example, we can not see, what is in your document preamble. From error can be suspect, that package `\dcolumn` is missing.

Comment: Here are the packages I am using

Comment: @Zarko already gave you the answer. Just delete the backslash.

Comment: Please tell me which specific blackslash are you talking about. The error is limited to the within the '\begin{tabular}{ l d{2.7} d{2.6} d{4.5} d{4.5}} ' argument

Comment: @Rafael, in my comment I have a typo (as try to tel you *cfr* in her comment): instead`\dcolumn` it should be `dcolumn`. And after then also definition of column type `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Your (first) error is caused because in your preamble are missed package `dcolumn` and definition for `d` column type:

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}                   
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}
```

After adding above to your document preamble, unfortunately new errors will arise :-(. To resolve it, I clean-up your code. In this I did:

- in preamble I delete duplicate of loaded packages (it is sufficient to load each package only ones)
- group packages regarding their purposes (all packages relevant for tables are loaded together)
- remove not defined `\smallscript{` command, which purpose is not clear
- redesign/correct use of `treepartable` (see MWE below).

After this changes I obtain:

[image]

MWE, which generate above image, is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\linespread{1.3}                   % you should decide, what you will use: 
                                    % doublespacing or linespread
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
%\linenumbers
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
%\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}                    % <-- added
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}}   % <-- added

\usepackage{lipsum}                     % for text filler

\begin{document}
\section{first}
\lipsum*[1]
    \begin{table}[ht] 
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
%\footnotesize
\caption{Determinants}
\begin{tabular}{ l d{2.7} d{2.6} d{4.5} d{4.5}}
    \hline\hline
                &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Fixed Effects Model} &&&             \\
first column    &   12.3456789  & 12.345678 &   12.34567    &   12.34567    \\
    \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
%
\begin{tablenotes}[para,raggedright]\footnotesize
    \item[***]  $p < 0.01$,
    \item[**]   $p < 0.05$,
    \item[*]    $p < 0.10$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note:* in future, when you will ask for help here (or elsewhere) for solving your LaTeX problems, always provide *Minimal Working Example* (MWE), which is small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` in its beginning, followed by preamble in which you consider only packages relevant to your problem. After preamble follows `begin{document}`, code which cause your problem (table in your case) and with `\end{document}` on the end. With this you will help people willing to help you :).

**Edit:**
I notice, that in your premble is package `booktabs`. Why you not use its rules in your in table(s)? With them they will have more professional looks:

[image]

For above table the code is:

```
\begin{tabular}{ l d{2.7} d{2.6} d{4.5} d{4.5}}
    \toprule
                &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Fixed Effects Model} &&&             \\
    \midrule
first column    &   12.3456789  & 12.345678 &   12.34567    &   12.34567    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```